Deck of cards question - solved but uncertain
I am a student studying statistics as a major and I am trying to solve the following question:
A deck of $n$ cards numbered $1$ through $n$ are to be turned over one at a time. Before each card is shown you are to guess which card it will be. After making your guess, you are told whether or not your guess is correct but not which card was turned over. It turns out that the strategy that maximizes the expected number of correct guesses fixes a permutation of the $n$ cards, say $1,\;2,\;\dots\;n$, and then continually guesses $1$ until it is correct, then continually guesses $ 2$ until either it is correct or all cards have been turned over, and then continually guesses $3$, and so on. Let $G$ denote the number of correct guesses yielded by this strategy.
Determine $P(G = k)$.
I solved this problem but I'm unsure since the answer is a bit complicated. I guess this could be more simplified and can anyone help me?
$P(G = 1) =\; P(\text{Card order must be } 2 \to 1) \;= \frac{_nC_2 · (n-2)!}{n!}$
$P(G = 2) =\;P(\text{Card order must be } 132,\,\,\, 312)\; = \frac{_nC_3 · 2 · (n-3)!}{n!}$
⋯
$P(G = k) = \frac{_nC_{k+1} · k · (n-k+1)!}{n!}$
Is my calculation correct or is there anything wrong?

For $G$ to be $1$ you must have $1$ come after $2$.  This seems to be what you mean with $2 \to 1$.  The probability of that is $\frac 12$ as the permutations with $1$ before $2$ match up with those with $2$ before $1$.  Your expression simplifies to this.
Your approach is evident in your expression for $n=3$.  You are correct that what matters is the order of the cards $1,2,3$ and two of the six possible orders work so the probability is $\frac 13$.  Your expression simplifies to this.  You have gotten your expression by choosing the locations for the three cards, multiplying by the number of orders of those cards work, multiplying by the number of ways to order the rest of the cards, and dividing by the total number of orders.  It would be much better to describe this in words so we understand your logic.
Your general expression claims that there are $k$ orders of the first $k+1$ cards that work.  I believe that is true, but please give the reasoning behind it like my last paragraph.  It is certainly not enough to claim that this is the pattern of the first two calculations.

Thanks for your advice :)
